# iMacros — Setting date to tomrrow and day after tomorrow

Tags: imacros

I have recorded an iMacro which deals with setting dates in two dropdown lists, tomorrow and day after tomorrow. But people who are using it have to edit the macro everyday to set the dates, including month if it's changing tomorrow or day after tomorrow.

I was wondering if imacro can do it automatically? Setting date 1 to tomorrow's date and date 2 to day-after-tomorrow date. And what about month? What if a new month starting tomorrow or day after tomorrow? Can imacro make some commonsense decisions by itself? :)

Comment: You can use the JavaScript scripting for that or pay someone to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. In the meantime, any free tips from you? :) BTW, is macroscripts.org down?

Comment: You can message me on website.

Answer (score 1):

This code outputs tomorrow day and day after tomorrow. Need to use Javascript and iMacros command EVAL.

```js
var today = new Date(); 
var tomorrow = new Date(); 
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1); 
var day = tomorrow.getDate().toString(); 
if (day.length < 2) {day = "0" + day;} 
var month = (tomorrow.getMonth() + 1).toString(); 
if (month.length < 2) {month = "0" + month;} 
var year = tomorrow.getFullYear().toString(); 
var tomorrowDateString = day + "/" + month + "/" + year; 

var afterTomorrow = new Date(); 
afterTomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 2); 
var day = afterTomorrow.getDate().toString(); 
if (day.length < 2) {day = "0" + day;} 
var month = (afterTomorrow.getMonth() + 1).toString(); 
if (month.length < 2) {month = "0" + month;} 
var year = afterTomorrow.getFullYear().toString(); 
var afterTomorrowDateString = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

alert('tomorrow: '+tomorrowDateString+'  after tomorrow: '+afterTomorrowDateString);
```

For iMacros this code will be look like this:

```
SET tomorrow EVAL("var today = new Date(); var tomorrow = new Date(); tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1); var day = tomorrow.getDate().toString(); if (day.length < 2) {day = \"0\" + day;} var month = (tomorrow.getMonth() + 1).toString(); if (month.length < 2) {month = \"0\" + month;} var year = tomorrow.getFullYear().toString(); var tomorrowDateString = day + \"/\" + month + \"/\" + year; tomorrowDateString;")
PROMPT {{tomorrow}}

SET afterTomorrow EVAL("var today = new Date(); var afterTomorrow = new Date(); afterTomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 2); var day = afterTomorrow.getDate().toString(); if (day.length < 2) {day = \"0\" + day;} var month = (afterTomorrow.getMonth() + 1).toString(); if (month.length < 2) {month = \"0\" + month;} var year = afterTomorrow.getFullYear().toString(); var afterTomorrowDateString = day + \"/\" + month + \"/\" + year; afterTomorrowDateString;")
PROMPT {{afterTomorrow}}
```